# Finding the best number of clusters including only one cluster (so no clustering)

Tags: statistical-significance, clustering, signal-processing

Suppose you have a number of small pieces of signal from a sensor. These snippets are found earlier using signal detection. These snippets can be real events or noise. I now want to cluster these signal pieces. There may be only noise, noise and events or only events per sensor.
In the case that a sensor has only events, I want all data to be assigned to a cluster instead of being split into multiple clusters.  (So that the following statistics are correct. These are not calculated on noise [only], so it does not matter if the case is split or not).

I have no ground truths but we classify the snippets later based on some heuristics and known properties of real events. Standard cluster metrics like Silhouette score etc. need at least 2 clusters.
My idea now would be to randomly cluster and see if "real" clusters would be significantly better than this random clustering. Are there any other ways to approach this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are "pieces of a signal from a sensor"?  How do you know if they are noise or signal?

What does "I want all data to be assigned to a cluster instead of being clustered." mean?

Also, many of the "rules" about deciding on clusters do include one cluster as a possibility.

Comment: I tried to update the question accordingly. We have signal snippets of the sensor, which are found using signal detection before (simple threshold crossing). Noise or signal will be determined by later by a custom classification. Could you point me to the rule you have in mind? Currently we used KMeans as cluster algorithm which works well, however it might be changed in the future. I know that DBSCAN  could assign to one cluster and noise. However, I fell less confident in finding the right parameters for these Cluster algorithm. Therefore we are currently using KMeans.

Comment: Imo standard clustering algorithms, e.g., k-means, ae not appropriate for your problem. Better solutions are available from information theoretic models such as Brandmaier's permutation distribution clustering, "Permutation distribution clustering is a complexity-based approach to clustering time series. The dissimilarity of time series is formalized as the squared Hellinger distance between the permutation distribution of embedded time series." He has developed R routines for this. https://brandmaier.github.io/pdc/

Comment: Thanks, @MikeHunter. Although the inital data is in form of a time series, we cluster mainly based on features derived from the snippets (e.g. min/max amplitude, PCA of time seriens). I not sure whether this PDC is still appropriate than.

Comment: Feature based clustering uses the moments of the pdfs, PDC does not. Imo, it would be a useful exploratory step to compare clustering with features vs PDC on the time series.